# Robot Framework can't find Python

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to install Robot Framework, but it keeps giving me an error message during setup that "No Python installation found in the registry."  I've tried running the installer as administrator, I've made sure that Python is installed (I've tried both 2.7.2 and 2.7.9), and both C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts are added to the PATH (with and without slashes on the end, if that matters).

I have no idea why it can't find Python.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have more than one python installation in your computer?

Comment: As far as I can tell I just have the one version.

Comment: You say you've tried version 2.7.2 and 2.7.9, yet you say you have C:\Python23, which seems to imply you have python 2.3 installed. Are you _certain_ you have python 2.7 installed? You should have a C:\Python27 folder.

Comment: That was a typo on my part.  The version I have is 2.7.2, and the PATH variable has C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts added to it

Comment: Please verify that the path doesn't contain "" and that you can run "python" from the command line.

Comment: 1. check your installation process
2. Check your path: ex: "other\path;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts"
3. Restart your command line / terminal and try again with "python"

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following path in environment variable also:

"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

Since this path consists all the third party modules installed on your PC and also verify if robot-framework library is present in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. 
Install a different bit version of ROBOT framework. In my case, I was first trying to install 64bit version but it said  "No Python installation found in the registry." 
Then I tried to install the 32bit version of ROBOT framework and it worked.
So there is nothing wrong with your Python version.